# Is it dangerous to recover my old home directory?

Tags: system-installation

My computer crashed recently. Afterwards, I was not able to start a session in graphic mode with Unity or Gnome. Is it dangerous to re-use my old home directory? Will I get the same errors?

Answer (score 1):

Don't reuse it. There are configurations and caches in `~/` that could have caused your initial issue (or cause further issues on the new install).

Instead of copying everything or using the old directory, only copy the files you need. Or, keep the directory somewhere easy to access and just take directly from that. It's just not a good idea to reuse a home directory.

Comment: Thank you, for the answer. I've not copy all the files.

Answer (score -1):

no, home is where your personal files are stored, system and settings are stored elsewhere

Comment: This isn't correct. There are _many_ configuration files stored in `~/`, including ones that could be causing graphical breakages.

Comment: It appears he may attempt to use it anyways.